# Rails - Mailboxer : delete from database if both participant deleted conversation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, mailboxer

I am trying to delete a conversation with MailBoxer gem. There's nothing included in the gem itself, but I think it's possible to do something like:

If both participants deleted the conversation, delete it from the database.

I started with something like this in my function "empty_trash", so like that, every time a participant click on the link "Empty Trash", it will check if the conversation has been deleted by both or not. If not, nothing happens, if yes, it will delete the conversation from the DB.

```
def empty_trash
    @conversations = current_user.mailbox.conversations
        @conversations.each do |conversation|
            conversation.receipts_for(current_user).update_all(deleted: true)
        end
    @delete_conversation = Mailboxer::Receipt.select(:notification_id,:deleted).
                                         group(:notification_id,:deleted).
                                         having("count(*) > 1")
    @delete_conversation.destroy_all
    redirect_to :back
end
```

So basically, what I am trying to do, is to group all conversation by :notification_id where deleted: true and then delete the matching result.

EDIT: DB

```
  t.string "receiver_type"
  t.integer "receiver_id"
  t.integer "notification_id", null: false
  t.boolean "is_read", default: false
  t.boolean "trashed", default: false
  t.boolean "deleted", default: false
  t.string "mailbox_type", limit: 25
  t.datetime "created_at", null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  t.boolean "is_delivered", default: false
  t.string "delivery_method"
  t.string "message_id"



  ID | NOTIFICATION_ID| DELETED |
  =================================
  1 | 9 | t | 
  2 | 9 | t | 
  3 | 8 | f |
  4 | 8 | t |
```

So in this example, the records with "Notification_id" 9, should be destroyed.

EDIT 2 - After you updated your answer :
I ended up with this, which is working, I just don't know if it's the cleaner approach, but at least it work.
I think later I will move to a home made messaging system, certainly more flexible.

```
def empty_trash
    @conversations = current_user.mailbox.conversations
        @conversations.each do |conversation|
            conversation.receipts_for(current_user).update_all(deleted: true)
        end

    @a = Mailboxer::Receipt.where(receiver_id: current_user.id)
    @b = Mailboxer::Receipt.where.not(receiver_id: current_user.id)

    @a.each do |a| 
    @b.each do |b|

        if a.notification_id == b.notification_id && a.deleted == true && b.deleted == true
            b.delete
            a.delete
        end

    end
    end
    redirect_to :back
end
```

Comment: add more info please

Answer (score 0):

**Updated answer**

```
@delete_conversation = []
@conversations = Conversation.mailbox.conversations
@conversations.each do |conversation|
 @conversations.each do |compareConv|
  if conversation.notification_id == compareConv.notification_id && conversation.deleted? && compareConv.deleted && conversation.receiver_id != compareConv.receiver_id
   @delete_conversation.push(conversation)
  end
 end
end
```

Comment: Thanks, but that will look for every records where deleted: true, but I want to delete it only if both of the participants actually deleted it.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, then you can pass a for iteration inside another for iteration, compare with a conditional and add to a list, you know what i would mean?
`if deleted_in_one? && deleted_in_two?`

Comment: Thank you, I got the idea, but I have no clue on how to implement that in my current code, could you develop it a little bit more?

Comment: all conversations from all users that match? also you can add two fields on notifications then, if a user delete, change this field to true, if the two fields going to true, then triggers delete for the conversation for delete just when happens.

Comment: I see, but on Mailboxer, you have two different entry : one for the send and one for the recipient, and each has a field called deleted and another called notification_id, which is the only one that allow you to identify if it's the same conversation or not. You approach would be good (and I did something like this once) but only if I didn't use Mailboxer. Do you want me to edit my post and add the structure of the database ?

Comment: i did the same you say (with node) for own old project, is this what you say. if you can, please, add the db structure.

Comment: I added the DB for mailer_receipts, so if records with same "notification_id" and if for both "deleted" is true -> destroy both. And trigger this action at the same time as "Empty Trash" .

Comment: :) Remember to vote answers and give correct answers!